# Ramda documentation style name

Tags: logic, symbols, ramda.js

I really enjoy the Rambda.js library. (https://ramdajs.com/)

However, I don't understand the method level shorthand documentation.

For example: R.Assoc shorthand documentation reads "**String → a → {k: v} → {k: v}**"

What is this style called and where can I find resources to help decipher these symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [long article](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Type-Signatures) on this in the Ramda wiki. There is also a briefer overview in [issue 2547](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2547#issuecomment-396615146).

These are mostly an attempt to adapt the Hindley-Milner type annotation to Javascript.